# Angular 2 / TypeScript multi line string in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angularjs, string, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am writing a custom component in Visual Studio Code and would like to assign a string value to a property. However I need to break the string into multiple lines. But whenever I do that VSCode gives me a list of problems.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: I can't break the string into multiple lines according to Visual Studio Code]

Answer (score 6):

You need to use backTick to include multi line String literals.
This is a feature of ES6

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 5):

You can break lines using `+` concatening operator:

```
template: "<h1>" +
    "</h1>"
```

Or ` backtick

```
template: `<h1>
    </h1>`
```

Or `\` backslash

```
template: "<h1>\
    </h1>"
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, Parth Ghiya's reply is the correct one.  Single quotes are no longer permissible for template strings: `Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.`